# Why is my property absent from the Realm object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm using Realm for persistence and I cannot access properties which are marked as readonly.

More accurately, I can print them using dot notation, but `po object` only shows the readwrite properties, and trying to access readonly properties using `objectsWhere` crashes.

I've tested using a standard NSObject class and the issue disappears (for `po` obviously), which makes me wonder why/if Realm ignores readonly properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct! If a property is marked as `readonly`, Realm ignores it and doesn't create a backing for it in the database file. This is the same implicit behavior as placing a method in the `ignoredProperties` method of `RLMObject`. They are left as traditional Objective-C properties. :)

If you need to make the property visible in the `po object` command, you can override the `- (NSString *)description` method of your object and ensure that your object is included in the description string that is printed.

Since `readonly` properties aren't backed by Realm, they'll be quite limited in what you can do with `objectsWhere`, as that uses a custom Realm query engine. You can probably check if other Realm properties match that property, but you couldn't create a query using the property itself as the item being searched for.