# Is my approach to readonly properties in Realm correct?

Tags: objective-c, realm, access-modifiers

Using Realm, I have found that readonly properties (as per the documentation and my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018843/why-is-my-property-absent-from-the-realm-object)) are not persisted, which I assume is for optimisation reasons.

Since I want to persist readonly properties (in that particular case, a staleness value derived from the creation date of an object), I've decided to use an empty setter.

- Interface file

  ```
  @property ( nonatomic, getter=isStale, setter=isReadonlyProperty:) bool stale;
  ```
- Implementation file

  ```
  - (bool) isStale {
      return [self secretComputationMethod];
   }


  - (void) isReadonlyProperty:(bool)stale {
      // ignore argument
      NSLog(@"Property is readonly");
  }
  ```

Is this an acceptable approach? Is there a better way? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of Realm's non-persistence of readonly properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ["Class extension"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3). In the header file, declare the property as `readonly`. In implementation file, you can override the property declaration, as follows.

#### TestObject.h

```
@interface TestObject : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property (readonly) BOOL state;

@end
```

#### TestObject.m

```
@interface TestObject ()

@property (readwrite) BOOL state;

@end

@implementation TestObject

@end
```